# generating new variables using data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I just wanted to generate new variables named y_avg_corn, y_avg_soybeans using existing variables y_corn and y_soybeans.

The following code is the one I am using.

```
setDT(df)[ YEAR <= 2011, y_avg_corn := mean(y_corn), by = countyfips]

setDT(df)[ YEAR <= 2011, y_avg_soybeans := mean(y_soybeans), by = countyfips]
```

However, I want to use forloop since I might have to use for many crops. The code that I think would be more efficient should look like

```
crop_list <- list("corn", "soybeans")

for (i in 1:length(crop_list)){

setDT(df)[ YEAR <= 2011, paste0("y_avg_", crop_list[i]) := mean(paste0("y_", crop_list[i])), by = countyfips]

}
```

Comment: you will need `mean(get(paste0("y_", crop_list[i])))`